# Прямой вывод звука из Ютуб в канал дискорда

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Хочу сделать музыкального бота сам.

Но проблема в выводе звука. Он берет аргументы, ищет в ютубе, берет href первого видео и выдает ссылку.

Я это сделал с помощью bs4 и requests. Дальше я хотел скачивать видео с помощью библиотеки pytube и воспроизводить его уже с помощью внутреннего ffmpeg в discord.py. Но пока файл скачается, пройдет много времени, что очень долго и топорно.

Можно ли как-нибудь выводить звук в канал дискорда прямо с ссылки ютуба?

Сам код приложу. Я не хочу, чтобы весь код сделали за меня. Мне нужна или библиотека, или способ вывода звука прямо в дискорд.

```py
import discord
import asyncio
import requests
from discord.ext import commands
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pytube import YouTube

TOKEN = 'тут был токен'
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')
yt_url = 'https://www.youtube.com/results?'

@bot.command()
async def play(ctx, *, arg):
    param = {'search_query': arg}
    r = requests.get(yt_url, params = param)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    for link in soup.find_all('a'):
        CheckForWatch = link.get('href')
        if '/watch' in CheckForWatch:
            yt = YouTube('https://youtube.com' + CheckForWatch)
            break
    yt.streams.filter(only_audio=True).first().download()
    await ctx.send('ready')

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Я видел это так:

- Берем аргументы после команды !play.
- Ищем по ним в ютубе с помощью requests
  С помощью bs4 берем href первого видео в поиске
- Скачиваем только звук с помощью pytube
- Проигрываем или добавляем в стэк на последнее место (можно с помощью другой команды менять местами треки)
- Удаляем

Comment: Уверен, что вам помогут ответы на [этот вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56060614/how-to-make-a-discord-bot-play-youtube-audio).